# How can I create an Office "all-in-one" DVD with all Office applications?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-office-2016

I have the DVDs (or downloaded ISOs, or archives) for the various Office products: stand-alone programs like Word and Excel, the full Office suite, and applications that are only bundled alone (Project, Visio).

Can they be placed in a single DVD (ISO, folder...) in such a way that I may choose what I want to install?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as simple as copying everything from the various archives in the same place (overwriting or skipping as needed, it really doesn't matter).

When you run `setup.exe` for any Office realease (from 2007 to 2016), it will automatically discover available products and prompt you with a menu to choose what to install.

**Bonus**: if you put in the setup files for *various languages*, the Office setup will even let you choose which one(s) you want to install!

For Office 2007, you simply need to put everything in the same place.

For Office 2010 or later, as there are x86 and x64 editions, you *should not* mix them; but if you start from a full DVD, which includes both releases, you will find an "x86" and an "x64" folder: inside each of them there is the full product setup with its own `setup.exe`, and they are wrapped by an *external* `setup.exe` placed in the DVD root which selects the right one for the current system.
You should use exactly the same approach, putting the setup files for x86 products in the "x86" folder and the files for x64 products in the "x64" one.

---

*(Ok, I just discovered this and wanted to share it with SF :-))*

Comment: Nice use of the Jepoardy QA ;) Do you want to double-post to SU as I'm sure it'll be useful there too... (Oh hey - you get votes for the question AND the answer, way to double-dip too ;))

Comment: @Farseeker, I could double post... but wouldn't it get closed?